# How to sort values alphanumerically that have different translations?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Imagine you want to store JSON data in the Azure DocumentDB like

```
[{
    id: 1,
    caption: "Name1"
    state: 'created'
},
{
    id: 2,
    caption: "Name2",
    state: 'active'
}]
```

In the User Interface the state values will be translated

```
created: Created (Lang 1) / Angelegt    (Lang2)
active:  Active  (Lang 1) / Bearbeitung (Lang2)
```

The result set of the query `SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.state` will get the documents in order `id 2, id 1`. The User Interface will display the translated data as "`Active`" and "`Created`". For the second language it will be "`Bearbeitung`" and "`Angelegt`".

For the first language the perceived sort order is **ascending** and for the second language **descending**. You can easily constuct a sample where there is **no perceived sort order** for the user if he looks at the translated values.

I am searching for a solution that gives the user a sort order of the translated values. Of course one solution is to query all items from DocumentDB and do the sorting on the client side. But I would like to avoid this (performance penalty for larger paged result sets) .

Can you give me a hint if there is a possible solution that places this kind of sort operation in the DocumentDB query ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. If you're storing the translated text in a property, you can just `order by` that property. Otherwise, this is going to be up to your app/server to deal with, as it has to build content dynamically based on translation lookups. And how you do that is a fairly broad discussion, with no right solution/answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - yes, one valid approach is to use more storage and store all translations inside the document. Alas, the  language dependent caption may be changed over time and then all existing data has to be modified. But this seems to be exactly the broad discussion you mentioned. I highly appreciate, if you have a pointer for me to where I can read more about this topic. I fear,  the magic I am searching for does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to solve this problem and there are pros and cons, based on which you need to make your tradeoffs:

- As you mentioned, in DocumentDB, you store only the English term. Then from the client side, you could read all the needed terms (with necessary filters and so on), and then translate the English terms to any other language that you desire and sort from the client side based on the translation result. With this approach, you save storage on the DocumentDB side. However, you will need to do sorting yourself on the client side.
- As David mentioned, you could store both the English term and the translated term in DocumentDB and then use DocumentDB SDK to do an ORDER BY query on the translated terms. You do need to store more data in DocumentDB. However, the benefit is that you will not need to manage and sort the data yourself. DocumentDB SDK and service handle all the hassle for you, especially if your collection is partitioned. The problem of updating the translated term would not prohibit you from adopting approach as DocumentDB handles update and replace document efficiently. You can also version your JSON documents and add new documents when translation needs to be changed, instead of modifying the existing one. You could also add new fields to the existing documents and keep multiple translated terms. There is this kind of flexibility in DocumentDB as it is schema-less.
- Instead of storing the translated term(s) in DocumentDB, if all you need is to sort the documents based on the translated terms, you could even store an ordinal field inside your document specifically for the ORDER BY purpose. That ordinal field needs to respect the ordering of the translated terms that you have. Depending on the number of translated terms and the frequency of the update, this could be a good choice that balance both the storage and the ease of use.

Hope that helps.

Best,

Lengning

P.S. DocumentDB supports Unicode. Therefore, you could store any translated terms in DocumentDB if you want.